# PHP - Compare string with array elements from an HTML textarea input

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare

I don't understand why my code is not working.  I want to compare a string against an array of data that has been exploded, and while it is being parsed thru.  For some reason I get a match on the first one, but not the remainders.  I would appreciate any help here!  I have looked and looked but no answer found!

By knowing which array element matches which string enables me to store that data properly and perform calculations on it.  The goal of this is to create a series of coordinates from raw survey data entered in a particular format.

I hope I have explained this well enough.  Like I mentioned I have searched for an answer and can't find one suited to what I am doing.

Thanks for any help I get, I appreciate it!

I have tried using in_array with no success, strcmp no success.

Sean

**Here is my code:**

```
   <?php
   $textArea = explode("\r", $_POST['textArea']);
   $i = 0;
   $j = 0;

   foreach ($textArea as $textRows) {
       $j = 0;
       $textRow = explode(",", $textRows);
       foreach ($textRow as $textItem[$i][$j]) {
           if ($j == 0) {
               if (("TR") == ($textItem[$i][$j])) {
                   echo("Traverse <br>");
               }
               if (("CP") == ($textItem[$i][$j])) {
                   echo("Control <br>");
               }
               echo("i = $i, j = $j, textItem = " . $textItem[$i][$j] . "<br>");
           }
           $j++;
        }
       $i++;
   }
   echo($textItem[9][0] . "<br>");
   echo($textItem[0][0] . "<br>");
   echo($textItem[0][3] . "<br>");
   echo($textItem[5][6] . "<br>");
   $_SESSION['textNum'] = $textItem;
   ?>
```

**My Test Data:**

```
CP,100,576.7873,6065.6221,12.542,CP
CP,101,6966.315,2226.4001,9.897,CP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,1,1.735,345.9961198,90.04410841,2964.26393,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,2,1.735,340.6589997,90.04021446,3080.322203,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,3,1.735,351.8639518,90.02168219,5448.892284,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,4,1.735,0,90.02469919,5316.851375,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,5,1.735,19.26823792,90.02318399,5441.916153,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,6,1.735,22.77896709,89.9901807,6138.435694,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,7,1.735,5.354105397,89.98465774,7551.171809,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,8,1.735,0,90.00156466,6884.324702,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,9,1.735,313.0231053,90.03002234,5137.515594,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,10,1.735,308.3168227,90.10108781,2655.989628,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,11,1.735,340.0064751,11.68927863,757.4152317,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,12,1.735,4.661110613,173.921569,776.3980052,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,13,1.735,89.44844992,89.87552303,484.2277925,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,14,1.735,169.5580845,89.57660413,273.6283687,PROP
TR,100,1.735,101,1.576,15,1.735,273.9971744,90.03246625,331.7785889,PROP
```

**My Current Output:**

```
Control
i = 0, j = 0, textItem = CP
i = 1, j = 0, textItem = CP
i = 2, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 3, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 4, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 5, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 6, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 7, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 8, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 9, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 10, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 11, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 12, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 13, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 14, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 15, j = 0, textItem = TR
i = 16, j = 0, textItem = TR
TR
CP
6065.6221
1.735
```

**What I want to see:**

```
Control
i = 0, j = 0, textItem = CP
Control
i = 1, j = 0, textItem = CP
Traverse
i = 2, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse
i = 3, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse
i = 4, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse
i = 5, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse
i = 6, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse
i = 7, j = 0, textItem = TR
```

etc...

Comment: Can you also provide the array you are matching it against and what exactly do you want to match

Comment: Thats in my code.  I don't get why this doesn't work:  ("TR") == ($textItem[$i][$j]) or ("CP") == ($textItem[$i][$j])

Comment: Uninitialized $i should emit a notice. Do you run with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`? You should. Add it as the first PHP line in your script.

Comment: They are 2 parts ... you said `Compare string with array` i can only see the string .. where is the array

Comment: And again .. in your code there is no place you are using `in_array`

Comment: Another thing that makes me wonder: Why is there a $j incremented in your code? If it is needed, then we are not seeing the real output from your script, or the real script from the output. Please check if your script posted is in fact the one that generated the output.

Comment: I just mentioned having tried in_array and strcmp to show I have tried solving this on my own.  The array is being entered in from the test data and is working fine.  I just want to see if [$i][0] equals TR or CP.  I don't program for a living but am trying to learn here so my lingo is probably a little off...

Comment: Is this something like this http://codepad.viper-7.com/bAB7LA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakdown the `$_POST` array on `"\n"` instead of `"\r"`, like this:

```
$textArea = explode("\n", $_POST['textArea']);

$i = 0;

foreach ($textArea as $textRows) 
{
    $j = 0;

    $textRow = explode(",", $textRows);

    foreach ($textRow as $textItem[$i][$j]) 
    {
        if ($j == 0) 
        {
            if (("TR") == ($textItem[$i][$j])) 
            {
                echo("Traverse <br>");
            }
            if (("CP") == ($textItem[$i][$j])) 
            {
                echo("Control <br>");
            }
           echo("i = $i, j = $j, textItem = " . $textItem[$i][$j] . "<br>");
       }
       $j++;
    }
   $i++;
}

echo($textItem[9][0] . "<br>");
echo($textItem[0][0] . "<br>");
echo($textItem[0][3] . "<br>");
echo($textItem[5][6] . "<br>");
```

See: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XltceQ for a working example.

Output:

```
Control 
i = 0, j = 0, textItem = CP
Control 
i = 1, j = 0, textItem = CP
Traverse 
i = 2, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 3, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 4, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 5, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 6, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 7, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 8, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 9, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 10, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 11, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 12, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 13, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 14, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 15, j = 0, textItem = TR
Traverse 
i = 16, j = 0, textItem = TR
TR
CP
6065.6221
1.735
```

Comment: It is initialized but didn't copy over for some peculiar reason.  Thats not the problem  I am having though.  My array is coming in just fine.  From my test input when the first element of a row equals CP it contains 6 elements.  When it contains TR there are 11 elements.  My question really is how do I compare that first element to figure out if it is a TR or CP?  In my code is $textItem[$i][$j], a string or is it still an array?  Could there be a problem with spaces being entered around $textItem[$i][$j] and that causing an inequality to occur?

Comment: In my mind its simple I can get $textItem[$i][$j] to show it equalling TR or CP why then doesn't it simply match to TR or CP when I ask if it is equal??

Comment: Take a look at the working example that I posted.  It results in the anticipated output.  Aside from formatting your test data as an array of strings (which might also me the issue - you didn't offer how that test data was being presented), the only change to your code that I made was the initialization of $i as I mentioned.  And... it works!  :)

Comment: My code was complete when I looked at it when editing but because I didn't hit enter and keep a space after my "Here is my code:" it snipped a bunch of code out...

Comment: Perhaps.  In that case, it's the formatting of the test data that is the issue, as the example at http://codepad.viper-7.com/09h05u works as intended.

Comment: I am more confused now...  you can get my code to work, but I can't...  Does it make a difference if the test code is pasted from a webpage?  It won't always be entered that way, sometimes typed in, or copied from a CSV file on the computer.  Could I be entering in a weird code or something without it being visible to me?

Comment: You don't have to iterate over the whole line if the only thing that is interesting to you is the first element after exploding the line. :)

Comment: No, it's not that, rather a difference in how I presented the test data - when I manually format it as a nested array, it works, but when I use explode to create it as such, I get your results.  The question is formatting the data initially - the rest of your code, while a bit cumbersome, does what you want it to do.

Comment: Got it!  Take a look at:   http://codepad.viper-7.com/XltceQ    Explode based upon \n instead of \r and it works all else being the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  I am looking all over the place trying to understand why I couldn't compare a string array to a string and instead it was all about how I was exploding my textarea.  The smallest little thing makes ALL the difference!  The answer to my problem was simply to replace \r in: $textArea = explode("\n", $_POST['textArea']); with \n.  \r is return and \n is newline.  I don't know why I lost 4 reputation points for this post, but I have my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Questions without wide applicability tend to get down-voted somewhat.  I'm glad we got it worked out for you, though.

Comment: Maybe this isn't a forum for someone who doesn't program for a living?  I am a Land Surveyor trying to learn a new skill.  In my opinion everyone needs to learn some form of programming skill.  I regret the beat down for seeking help...

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate that it impacts a user's karma (That's why I won't downvote a narrow question).  It would be nice if there were an option to downvote the question (so that it ranks lower in searches - signal-to-noise and all that) without impacting the questioner.  Stick with it - you're 100% right that it's a skill everyone should have.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciated it very much!